# XJC Error Suggesting "chameleon schema"

Tags: xml, compiler-errors, xsd, xjc

I'm having a problem running XJC against my schema.  I've removed almost all of the definitions from the schema, leaving the bare minimum to reproduce the problem.  When I run XJC against this minimal schema:

```
 1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 2 <xs:schema id="Catalog" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
 3
 4   <xs:element name="Attribute">
 5     <xs:complexType>
 6       <xs:simpleContent>
 7         <xs:extension base="xs:string">
 8           <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" />
 9         </xs:extension>
10       </xs:simpleContent>
11     </xs:complexType>
12   </xs:element>
13  
14   <xs:element name="SampleSet" substitutionGroup="Attribute"/>
15 </xs:schema>
```

I get the following XJC error:

```
C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\JMish>del src\jmish\jaxb\*.java

C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\JMish>xjc -d src -p jmish.jaxb JMish.xsd
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "jmish.jaxb.Attribute" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 5 of file:/C:/Users/mbmas_000/workspace/JMish/JMish.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "Attribute" is generated from here.
  line 5 of file:/C:/Users/mbmas_000/workspace/JMish/JMish.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) This confusing error happened most likely because the schema uses a technique called "chameleon schema", which causes a single definition to be loaded multiple times into different namespaces. See http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=18631 for more about this.
  line 5 of file:/C:/Users/mbmas_000/workspace/JMish/JMish.xsd

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 5 of file:/C:/Users/mbmas_000/workspace/JMish/JMish.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 5 of file:/C:/Users/mbmas_000/workspace/JMish/JMish.xsd

Failed to produce code.

C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\JMish>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Yet.... If I change the name of `SampleSet` to anything else, like `xSampleSet`, XJC completes with no errors.  I'm using XJC version 2.2.4-2 from JDK 1.7.0_45.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is `SampleSet` some sort of reserved element name?

Comment: For what it's worth, the schema looks valid to me, and to Saxon.  No chameleon include is happening here.  So looks like an XJC issue.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a bug too.  The same error occurs running XJC version 2.2.8-b130911.1802 from JDK 8u20.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is NOT a chameleon schema issue.

I think this is happening because both of the element `Attribute` and its anonymous inner complex type get their own classes. And both are named `Attribute`.

Try customizing the complex type to use another name:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="..." node="/xs:schema">
  <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='Attribute']/xs:complexType">
    <jaxb:class name="AttributeType"/>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

(Rough sketch, untested.)

Or use [`nameXmlTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html).

I don't think it is a bug.